# Is the trace=true Page attribute in aspx adding all these server variables and revealing the local IP in the HTML?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I have been wracking my brain around things that *might reveal the server IP of a hosted solution.* I came across the following as per the pen tester report.

**Notes on the screenshot:**

- I have blurred out the website URL
- The highlighted says: `default.aspx`
- The server IP is shown as seen in rectangle box in the screenshot.

[image: Pen tester report]

**Contents of `default.apsx`**(The highlighted filename in screenshot)

```
<%@ Page language="c#" Codebehind="default.aspx.cs" AutoEventWireup="True" Inherits="umbraco.UmbracoDefault" trace="true" validateRequest="false" %>
```

**My question:**

As per [MSDN for this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/aspnet/bb386420(v%3Dvs.100)#:~:text=true%20to%20enable%20tracing%20for,page%20to%20true%20or%20false.&text=true%20to%20display%20trace%20both,in%20the%20trace%20viewer%20(Trace.) issue, I am suspecting that the attribute `trace="true"` is giving away the IP.

*Could that be giving away the IP?*

*Also, would that affect the logging that is present in the code if I switch it to `false`?*

**Note:** As a developer I am not allowed access to debug this issue in Production, so this is one of those instances where I have to work on instincts and suspicions.

**Update:**

I do see one line of code in another file, though I investigated that it should not return hardcoded IPs. But let me know if you think if removing this can be a solution. This is part of the `Page_Load` function

```
Response.AddHeader("REFRESH", "0; URL=https://" + Request.ServerVariables["SERVER_NAME"] + Request.ServerVariables["PATH_INFO"] + (strQueryString == "" ? "" : "?" + strQueryString));
```

Comment: We don't exactly have an HTML that looks like that. So the only clue i have from the report is the `default.aspx` file. Just one line content as you can see

Comment: Yes and we have disabled all properties from web.config and used URL rewrite

Comment: Yes the pen tester is using Nessus. But we have converted all the IPs to fully qualified domain name. But do you think switching trace to `false` will work ?

Comment: Yeah but nowhere we are returning the IPs from code side, we checked in all environemtns

Comment: I think i am closing on the issue. Thanks to you sir. If you look at the update, i came across a code that is adding response.header with information about sever nameetc. I think removing that from page_load should solve this

Comment: https://odetocode.com/articles/242.aspx - it appears I was wrong. I’ve deleted my other comments. There also another setting to determine if the trace is written to the page. I would keep it open.

Comment: Ok so it is confirmed that `trace=true` might be the culprit here.

Comment: I would definitely disable it on production in either case. There maybe also be another configuration also in play. I’ve edited the title to reflect “all server variables”. The IP is just one of them.

Comment: But would that affect logging mechanism because a lot of times developers depend on logs to debug things, and switching off tracing should not affect those.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to find 2 solutions to this problem. I would like to post it here in case it would help someone in future.

**Code side solution**

It turns out the `trace=true` was the culprit here. Based on the documentation [here](https://odetocode.com/articles/242.aspx), thanks to *@user2864740* I tried to change it back to `false` and it stopped the trace.

**Server-side solution**

Additionally, we can also disable trace messages altogether in Production using an entity in IIS - *[Request Filtering](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/manage/configuring-security/configure-request-filtering-in-iis#:%7E:text=Request%20filters%20restrict%20the%20types,rules%20that%20you%20set%20up.)*

**Disable HTTP TRACK and TRACE**

In order to disable the HTTP TRACK verb, please follow the instructions below. This vulnerability might be flagged because of allowing HTTP TRACE verb as well so that It’s a good idea to disable both.

- Go to IIS Manager
- Click the website name
- Double click “Request Filtering” (If you don’t see Request Filtering icon, please install it)
- Go to “HTTP Verbs” tab
- Click “Deny Verb” from the Actions menu. Type “TRACE”. Click “OK”
- Click “Deny Verb” from the Actions menu. Type “TRACK”. Click “OK”

[image: ref1]

**Testing**

If you want to test if this setting works, you can try to send a TRACE request to IIS via telnet. If it fails with 404 code, it means this request is blocked. Steps to test the setting:

- In your client machine, open Command Prompt
- Type telnet  80
- Type the text below. Continue to enter characters even though the window won’t show what you are typing

  1. TRACE / HTTP/1.1
  2. Host: websitedomain.com
  3. HostA: Hello
- Hit Enter twice

If it shows HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found, it means the setting is working. TRACE is disabled:

[image: ref4]

If it shows HTTP/1.1 200 OK, it means the setting is not working. TRACE is allowed:

[image: ref5]

The only downside to this method is you won't see any trace messages at all. So if that seems to be a concern you should go with code side solution.